# How to have a tkinter button lead to a python shell

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, button

I'm designing a program that will have a main menu with multiple buttons. When clicked, I want the buttons to lead to a Python shell for user input.

This is the main menu code:

```
from tkinter import *
import os

def main_account_screen():
    global main_screen
    main_screen = Tk()
    main_screen.geometry("300x250")
    main_screen.title("Menu Screen")
    Label(text="Menu", bg="pink", fg="magenta", width="300", height="2",
          font=("Calibri", 13)).pack()
    Label(text="").pack()
    Button(text="View timetable", height="2", width="30",).pack()
    Label(text="").pack()
    Button(text="Register/login", height="2", width="30").pack()

    main_screen.mainloop()

main_account_screen()
```

So where/how do I add code to lead these buttons onto a Python shell file?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are working on Linux based or under WSL, the quick short method is to attach calling script functions to the command parameter of the Button widget as follow:

```
from tkinter import *
import os


def timeTableCallBack():
    os.system('python $(pwd)/ViewTimeTable.py')

def loginCallBack():
    os.system('python $(pwd)/RegisterLogin.py')

def main_account_screen():
    global main_screen
    main_screen = Tk()
    main_screen.geometry("300x250")
    main_screen.title("Menu Screen")
    Label(text="Menu", bg="pink", fg="magenta", width="300", height="2",
          font=("Calibri", 13)).pack()
    Label(text="").pack()
    Button(text="View timetable", height="2", width="30",command= timeTableCallBack).pack()
    Label(text="").pack()
    Button(text="Register/login", height="2", width="30",command= loginCallBack).pack()

    main_screen.mainloop()

main_account_screen()
```

Comment: I'm on macos would this be applicable to that?

Comment: Yeah, I just test it out on macOS Mojave, and it's working normally.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by defining a function that does what you want and then specifying it via the `command=` option when creating the `Button`s.

Here's some [documentation](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/button.html) on what options `Button`a have.

In this case the function spawns a separate process running a separate copy of the Python interpreter via the `subprocess` module.

```
import subprocess
import sys
from tkinter import *


def main_account_screen():
    global main_screen

    main_screen = Tk()
    main_screen.geometry("300x250")
    main_screen.title("Menu Screen")

    Label(text="Menu", bg="pink", fg="magenta", width="300", height="2",
          font=("Calibri", 13)).pack()
    Label(text="").pack()
    Button(text="View timetable", height="2", width="30", command=python_shell).pack()
    Label(text="").pack()
    Button(text="Register/login", height="2", width="30", command=python_shell).pack()

    main_screen.mainloop()


def python_shell():
    """Run Python shell in a separate console."""
    subprocess.run(sys.executable, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)


main_account_screen()
```